# How can I realize get_search_results function in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django

ModelAdmin.get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
New in Django 1.6.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results

for some reasons, to be compatible with django 1.5

How to do this in django 1.5

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'age')
    search_fields = ('name',)

    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        # search_term is what you input in admin site, queryset is search results
        queryset, use_distinct = super(PersonAdmin, self).get_search_results(request, queryset, search_term)
        try:
            search_term_as_int = int(search_term)
            queryset |= self.model.objects.filter(age=search_term_as_int)
        except:
            pass
        return queryset, use_distinct
```

Comment: May I know why bitwise OR(|) is used here?

Comment: @ManishMeshram just for example, sql or query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try https://github.com/sivaa/django-custom-search-filter or u may try this [Django admin search: how to override the default handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538999/django-admin-search-how-to-override-the-default-handler)

Comment: Thank you,Obayhan, but it becomes complex,not what I want